# Multi update boolean state with checkboxes (Rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml

well this problem I'm sure it isn't difficult at all but being new to rails I'm kinda lost.
After watching Railscasts Episode #52, I went on to make my own publish/unpublish list of slides.

So this is the form view

```
    = form_tag publish_admin_category_slides_path(@cat4), :method => "put"  do 
#pricing    
    %table#plans
        %thead
            %tr
                %th Image
                %th Published

        %tbody
        - @image.each do |im|
            %tr.odd
                %td
                    = image_tag im.avatar.url(:thumb)

                    = link_to "Delete", admin_category_slide_path(@cat4,im), :method =>  "delete"

                    %span is

                %th 
                    = check_box_tag "slide_published[]", im.published ,im.published
```

With controller action #publish

```
    def publish

    Slide.update_all(:published => params[:slide_published])
    redirect_to :action => "index"
    end
```

What would be the correct way to write something like this?
A list with  checkboxes that changes boolean state of an attribute and multi updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some xp l8r I was able to find something like this.
I post it in case someone has a similar problem

```
def publish

            @cat = Category.find(params[:category_id])
          if params[:slide_published]
             checked_slides = Slide.find(params[:slide_published])

          end

          unless checked_slides.blank?
            @cat.slides.all.each do |slide|
                if checked_slides.include?(slide)     
                    slide.update_attribute :published, true unless slide.published?   
                else
                    slide.update_attribute :published, false unless !slide.published?   
                end
            end
          end

          if checked_slides.blank?
            @cat.slides.all.each do |slide|

                slide.update_attribute :published, false unless !slide.published?
            end
          end
```